# Multiple flat style drawer navigation menu with jQuery

Tags: jquery, navigation, drawer, flat

I am trying to make a new super fast menu for a website with jQuery, he is copyrighted under MIT licences so feel free to take what you want and re-use.

I am a rookie in javascript, my problem is on the drawer itself, I can't call a second and a third different drawer with 2 other link for display the 2 another `<ul>`.

DEMO available here: [DEMO](http://mayapi.xtremegaming.fr/essai/multiple_drawer/topdrawer.html)

My method seems very wrong and I do only bad manipulation when I try to duplicate the CSS file. I'm sure it is only some line in the jQuery but I have try many times with rename all files and adjust the anchors and no good result except for the first drawer who work very fast and perfectly.

[Code snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/Cudex/eqfwz7zu/5/)

```
<!-- here is the part i try to call with another drawer independent of the first, he have to appear when user click on <a> link 2 -->
<div class="drawer2-main drawer2-default">
    <nav class=" drawer2-nav" role="navigation" style="transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.57, 0.1, 1); -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.57, 0.1, 1); transition-duration: 0ms; -webkit-transition-duration: 0ms; transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);">
        <ul class="drawer2-menu">
            <li class="drawer2-menu-item">
                <ul class="drawer2-submenu">
                    <li class="drawer2-submenu-item">
                        <a href="">Work</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="drawer2-submenu-item">
                        <a href="">House</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

My question is: How I can call, like the first drawer, the two others drawers and `ul` separately?

Comment: Ok sorry to bother the community, after 2 days of hard dev, it work !!     https://jsfiddle.net/Cudex/eqfwz7zu/6/